# New PC can only boot from installation usb with windows 8.1 - Dell OptiPlex 3070

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb

Let me start by saying i have Propriety Applications that can only work with Windows 8.1/8/7 and is not compatible with Windows 10.

My old PC died on me and i bought a new PC (Dell OptiPlex 3070) which came with Windows 10 already installed. I did my research and found out that, i can have both Windows 10 and Windows 8.1 run on the PC, all i have to do is choose the OS i want to use during the boot process. So i followed the instructions and realized that Windows 8.1 cannot install because the partition i created is GPT format.
So, i went to Command Prompt and it displayed only one drive and i converted it to a MPR drive and "Cleaned" it (Thus completely eradicating Windows 10). I then went into the BIOS and changed the BOOT Sequence to Legacy from UEFI and added a boot option of a CD Drive (CD/DVD/USB/SD Drive)

I again restarted the PC for it to boot from the DVD/USB port but, I got the error message "Windows could not configure one or more system components. To install Windows, restart the computer and then restart the installation".

I remedied the error by executing the commands (in CMD) displayed below:

1. net user administrator /active:yes
2. net user administrator mypass
3. cd oobe
4. msoobe

The Windows 8.1 finally installed. The only problem is that the PC can only boot with the DVD Drive (OS installation disk) connected via the USB port.
I tried booting with the Disk drive disconnected and it says there is no drive to boot from. So I have to keep my Disk drive connected for Windows 8.1 to boot.
I went back to the BIOS to change the boot sequence to UEFI but there were no boot options.

Any ideas on how to make the PC boot from the C: drive will be deeply appreciated.